# Check if the user_id is exist inside query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've tried to query using laravel eloquent where user is following a specific brand.

The problem: How to query listing of brand and let me know if current login user is following the brand?

got 3 tables:

Brand:

```
Id | name | logo
```

User:

```
Id | name | email | password
```

Followers:

```
brand_id | user_id
```

Now i tried to query all brand and inside of the collection i want to add

```
 is_follow = 1 or is_follow = 0
```

if the user already follow or 0 if not exists.

I'm using fractal so maybe it can be easier to query. but i don't really get it how to query it out with check the user_id first.

Thanks

*Update

I manage to solve it. But i think its a bad practice.

```
  $user_id = Request::get('user_id');

  foreach($brands->followers as $value){
        $array[] = $value->user_id;
    }

    if(in_array($user_id, $array)){
        $is_follow = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the authenticated `User` follows a specific `Brand` with:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$exists = $user->brands->contains($brand_id);
```

You can also do it with a raw query which will be better in terms of performance:

```
$exists = DB::table('user_brand')
    ->whereBrandId($brand_id)
    ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
    ->count() > 0;
```

Comment: I can't use the second one. because i want listing all the brand. and put is_follow inside it. 

for the first one i'm still try using that.

Comment: Where do you want to add `is_follow` and why do need that? You already know if a user is following a brand or not through your relations.

Comment: I'm using it for front API. when i query all the brand i want to know if user has already followed that brand so they can't follow again. Just like twitter.

Comment: Is `is_follow` a column of your `brands` table? Can't your front API access Laravel? I don't understand why you would need the `is_follow`. On a side note, looks like we are drifting into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: nope. is_follow not in the table. but the followers table contain the user_id and brand_id. from that table i want to check if the following user is follow or not when querying the brand list.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need that extra `is_follow` parameter and where it is stored. You already know if and what users follow a brand at any moment.

Comment: I'm not storing "is_follow" column anywhere. I've update my question with answer.maybe it can help make more clearer. but i think my answer not best practice.